# Asynchronous methods and object destruction

Tags: dart

If I initiate an object from a class, and call one of its asynchronous methods , then destroy the object before the functions finishes executing .. will the asynchronous function keep executing or will it be stopped ?

Comment: why not try out to see what happens?

Comment: how do you mean exactly by "destroy the object"? Calling dispose on it?

Comment: It will keep executing.

Comment: because the asynchronous function became a closure hence keeps the object alive? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: There is no such thing as "destroy the object" in Dart. If you don't explicitly hold a reference to the object the event queue still does. When nothing references the instance GC will eventually dispose of it.